# Can't access state when pressing key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const inpt = useRef();

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, []);

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(message); 
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input ref={inpt} type="text" name="" id="" value={message} onChange={(e)=> setMessage(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click on the button I can log `message` correctly, but when I press the "Enter" key `message` logs as the initial value `""`.

Can you help me understand why this happening and what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `message` a dependency of the effect, as Ravi stated.

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;
    
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => inputRef.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, [message]);

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(`MESSAGE: ${message}`); 
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <input ref={inputRef} type="text" value={message} onChange={(e)=> setMessage(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

### Use a form

I better way to do this would to use a form. It has built-in <kbd>Enter</kbd> key support.

If you are using a ref on the field, you do not need to store a state!

```js
const { useCallback, useRef } = React;
    
function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Do not navigate away from current page
    console.error(`MESSAGE: ${inputRef.current.value}`); 
  }, [inputRef]);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input ref={inputRef} type="text" name="message" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using empty dependency array in `useEffect` hook, upon re-renders due to the state changes, its cleanup function wont get executed and `ref` will keep pointing to stale `input` element.
To avoid this, you should add `message` or `handleKeydown` as dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, [message]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue here is that the keydown event listener is instantiated ***once*** and closes over the `message` state value in the `handleKeyDown` callback scope from the initial render cycle when the listener is created. It will never receive any updated `message` value to console log.

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In
> other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope
> from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time
> a function is created, at function creation time.

See [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more details.

## Solutions

### Use proper `useEffect` dependency

A trivial solution is to simply add the `message` state to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so that each time it is updated the previous keydown listener is removed and a new "instance" is created with the current `message` state value closed over in scope.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
}, [message]);
```

#### Demo

```js
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  const inpt = React.useRef();

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, [message]);

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(message);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inpt}
        type="text"
        name=""
        id=""
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

### Cache `message` state in React ref

The constant adding/removal of event listeners is work though. A slight improvement would be to use a React ref to cache the current `message` state value so the listener only needs to be instantiated once. The code updates the ref value and the ref itself is a stable reference so the closure issue is avoided.

```js
const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
const messageRef = React.useRef(message);
...
  
messageRef.current = message;

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    handleClick();
  }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
}, []);

function handleClick() {
  console.error(messageRef.current);
}
```

#### Demo

```js
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  const messageRef = React.useRef(message);
  const inpt = React.useRef();
  
  messageRef.current = message;

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    inpt.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => inpt.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, []);

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(messageRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inpt}
        type="text"
        name=""
        id=""
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

### Use the `onKeyDown` event handler directly on the `input` element

Many would consider using the `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks to instantiate the keydown listeners like you've done a bit of a React anti-pattern. You can directly attach a `keydown` event handler to the `input` element. This avoids the stale closure problem ***and*** the need for the extra logic to handle the listener and synchronization of state in a callback. It's much cleaner code and the method I recommend.

```
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(message);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name=""
        id=""
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Demo

```js
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };

  function handleClick() {
    console.error(message);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name=""
        id=""
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```